# Intersection type of nested array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Though the type intersection works fine for such example:

```js
type Merged = (
    { lorems: { foo: string }[] } &
    { lorems: { bar: string }[] }
);

const x: Merged;

x.lorems[0].foo; // ok
x.lorems[0].bar; // ok
```

But none of the array methods supports the type intersection, for example:

```js
x.lorems.shift().foo; // ok
x.lorems.shift().bar; // doesn't exist???
```

But with such a hack it works:

```js
(x.lorems.shift() as typeof x.lorems[0]).bar;
```

Is there some way to create unioned type with nested array intersactions?

Comment: Try to make intersection only for foo and bar

Comment: @captain-yossarian Both Types in intersection are third party types, that's why we can't modify the array types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create the Type util, which will extract the Types from nested arrays and creates new array with intersected type.

```js
export type IntersectionTypeWithArrays<T1, T2, arrayKeys extends (keyof T1 & keyof T2)> = (
    Omit<T1, arrayKeys> &
    Omit<T2, arrayKeys> & {
        [key in arrayKeys]: (
            (T1[key] extends Array<infer U1> ? U1 : never) & 
            (T2[key] extends Array<infer U2> ? U2 : never)
        )[]
    }
);
```

And later the type intersection would look like this:

```js
let x: IntersectionTypeWithArrays<LoremsFoo, LoremsBar, 'lorems'>;

x.lorems.shift().bar; // ok
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a union type and a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) of some form.

If an object can be one of multiple different types, in order to be type safe. TS needs to be able to discriminate something is of a type or not somehow.

```
interface Type1 { shared: string; lorems: { foo: string }[] };
interface Type2 { shared: string; lorems: { bar: number }[] };
type TypeUnion = Type1 | Type2;

function getLorems(x: TypeUnion) {
  const t = x.lorems.shift();
  x.shared; // This is ok
  if ("foo" in t) t.foo;
  if ("bar" in t) t.bar;
}
```

Comment: Union is logically not correct. As the type (or the object) always contains both properties. That's why having all this conditions in code is not required.

Comment: @tenbits I don't know the use case so I'm guessing. But if the object you're expecting always has both properties why are the third party interfaces split into two models? That's the incorrect typing. Think about it. How you can say an object property is simultaneously "one thing" and a "different thing" at the same time? You are merging two different types together that don't look the same. Alike to saying my `array` is also a `string`... versus my `array` or a `string`.

Comment: Those are the data models, not something backed by classes. I consume several streams of data and merge them into a single data object. But not by the shallow merge but the deep merge.

Comment: What is also weired, that direct access an array item by index in typescript preserves type instersction `x.lorems[0].bar;` is ok, but `x.lorems.shift().bar;` is an error.